# Can you say "latest read chapter"?

Tags: phrase-request

Me and my friend are constructing an online forum, and as to avoid spoiling others we want every member to be able to display what chapter they're on in the manga, as well as how far they've come in the show. When explaining what chapter and/or episode you have reached of something, how should you phrase it?

We were thinking something along the lines of *"Latest read manga chapter"* and *"latest watched anime episode*," but is that really grammatically correct? Or should it be something like *"latest manga chapter read"* instead?

Is there another way of phrasing it perhaps?

Comment: Latest means the one you read most recently (time-wise), but doesn't necessarily mean it's the last one you read in terms of existence (e.g. you can have read chapters 1-5, then you decide read 3 again, in that case the latest you've read is 3, but the last is more ambiguous and works in both cases), so I would go with "Last read chapter".

Comment: As for your particular phrasing, even if you decide to go with "Latest", it should be "**latest/last anime episode watched**" and "**latest/last manga chapter read**", putting the verb at the end of the clause.

Comment: *Last chapter read* has the same ambiguity as does *latest chapter read*. I was gonna suggest *Furthest chapter read* but that can also be somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Netflix does this by saying "Continue watching..." which implies you would start where you last left off. Resume is another word that might work.

Comment: @MorganFR: I got that exactly the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

If there were three manga released in January, February, and March, and you read the March one first, followed by the February one, then the last read manga is the one from February, and the latest read manga is the one from March.

The "last read" is the one that you read last. The "latest read" is the latest manga (the latest released) among those that you read.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider *furthest chapter read*, because both *latest chapter read* and *last chapter read* do not necessarily designate the furthest chapter that the person has read; they refer to the most recent chapter read, which doesn't necessarily mean the furthest chapter they've read. They could have read through Chapter 5, then after that reread Chapter 3, which would then be both the last and latest chapter that they've read. But in this case, the "furthest chapter" they've read is still Chapter 5. A problem is that *furthest  chapter* is not a common expression, and native speakers tend not to use *furthest* that often. We usually just ask *How far have you read in a book or watched in a TV series?* Or *How far have you gotten?* In answer to the similar *How far have you ever gotten?* you might hear *The furthest I've (ever) gotten is to Chapter 33*. People, even native speakers, tend to confuse *furthest* and *farthest*, which could partially explain people's reticence to use it/them. See [further/farther](http://grammarist.com/usage/farther-further/) at the Grammarist.